# Почему не вызывается финализатор

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора, деструктор

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при выполнении данного кода не будет выполнен финализатор?

```
using System;

namespace Where_Destructor
{
    class Foo : IDisposable
    {
        public String s;
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am constructed");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am disposed");
        }


        ~Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am destructed");                
        }
     }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo f;
            using (f = new Foo())
            {

            }
            f = null;
            GC.Collect();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Результатом будет:

> I am constructed 
>   I am disposed

Однако, если мы изменим код на такой:

```
using System;

namespace Where_Destructor
{
    class Foo : IDisposable
    {
        public String s;
        public Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am constructed");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am disposed");
        }


        ~Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am destructed");                
        }
     }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo f = new Foo())            
            f = null;
            GC.Collect();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

то финализатор вызывается вполне успешно.

Результат:

> I am constructed
>   I am destructed

Comment: A что у вас финализатор? Я вижу только деструктор и dispose.

Comment: Почитал предыдущие посты, везде все твердили что деструкторов в C# нет, есть только финализаторы)

Comment: Здесь разъясняется когда, зачем и как реализовать IDisposable https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337005/3129992

Comment: @Tzarek, по идее, он бы не вызывался лишь в том случае, если бы вы написал в Dispose GC.SuppressFinalize, однако, его нет. Быть может впоследних редакция что-то подкрутили и он добавляется неявно. Рихтер писал, что Финализатор- это защита от того, что программист забудет закрыть ресурс.

Comment: Проверил: у меня в обоих случаях " I am destructed" выводится _после_ `Console.ReadKey` (нажатия на клавишу).

Answer (score 5):

Финализатор в первом варианте не вызывается по нескольким причинам:

1. Финализатор не обязательно отрабатывает в момент сборки мусора. Даже наоборот, объект с финализатором продолжит жить после сборки мусора, ради того, чтобы системный поток смог вызвать на нем финализатор.
2. Вы проверяете ваш код в Debug сборке. В Debug время жизни локальных переменных может продлеваться ради удобства отладки. Дебаггер вполне мог пометить первое значение f как живущее до конца метода.

Если хотите получить гарантированный вызов финализатора - допишите ручное ожидание и проверяйте в Release:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo f;
    using (f = new Foo())
    {

    }
    f = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Но почему же во втором варианте кода финализатор вызывается сразу же?

Comment: @Tzarek он вызывается в стороннем потоке, а не сразу же - просто вы не успеваете это заметить. Ну отладчик решил, что значение не используется, и объект был собран - бывает. Сборка мусора в .net недетерминирована. Нет никаких гарантий что объект убьет именно при вызове GC.Collect(), а не раньше или не намного позже. Это плата за эффективность GC.

Comment: Ну смотрите, @PashaPash,  конструкция using у нас должна как бы раскладываться в try-finally, так? По сути, никакой магии. Однако, если мы наш исходный код перепишем в виде: Foo f = new Foo(); try {} finally{f.Dispose()} и далее, то все отрабатывает как надо и финализатор вызывается. Получается дело в using?

Comment: @Tzarek дело в том, что при определении границ "эта переменная видна от строки а до строки б" GC использует данные от JIT. Данные эти в виде "в таком-то регистре лежит ссылка на переменную до такой-то инструкции, а дальше - не лежит" (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/05/09/garbage-collection-and-variable-lifetime-tracking/). В отладке время жизни переменных продлевается, на усмотрение JIT. Так что у вас вполне может быть две одновременных локальных переменных f - одна мусорная, ссылающаяся на Foo, вторая - ссылающаяся на null. И обе видны (с точки зрения GC) до конца

Answer (score 1):

Проверил ваш код на двух версиях фреймворка: 4.7 и 4.0.
Проверил в режимах Debug и Release. Итого 4 варинта.

На обеих версиях фреймворка поведение одинаковое. Оно зависит от дебага/релиза.

В Debug "I am destructed" не выводится (вернее, выводится уже после нажатия на клавишу, после `Console.ReadKey`).

В Release "I am destructed" выводится сразу.

Вывод: цитата **PashaPash**

> В Debug время жизни локальных переменных может продлеваться ради удобства отладки.

Answer (score 0):

Использование конструкции `using(...) { }` гарантирует вызов `Dispose()` при выходе за пределы `using(){ }`.